# Wordpress website working fine on localhost but not displaying front pages on webhost

Tags: plugins, front-end, debug, frontpage, hosting

The website works perfect on my localhost.
I used duplicator plugin to upload it on my web-host. 
Database connections are established since mywebsite.com/wp-admin works perfect. I can login the wordpress wp-admin panel and all the plugins, pages, posts are there and are editable.
Also the permalink on the homepage shows as http://mywebsite.com

But when I open my website I see an absolutely blank page. There is no code in inspect element or no errors in console log.

Website can be viewed at: www.maajees.com.pk

**Things I've tried:**

1. Reupload the files from duplicator.
2. Disabled all the plugins, no result.
3. Wp-Admin > Settings > Permalinks selected another format and then selected the same format as localhost and clicked save settings, didn't work.
4. I created a php file called index.php, renamed the wordpress file index.php to index2.php temporarily and placed an h1 tag "Testing" in index.php, I can view testing when I opened the domain www.maajees.com.pk which means the domain is properly configured. Changed back the wordpress index2.php file back to index.php.

Nothing worked. All suggestions are welcome. Thank You

**Summary**

Only localhost everything works perfect but when I upload it on webhost no page is displayed. website.com/wp-admin and all wordpress backend works perfect but still nothing is being displayed on the www.mywebsite.com

Comment: Have you checked your `wp-config.php` file to make sure it's pointing to the correct (live) database with a valid user?

Answer (score 0):

May be the active theme is overridden. Check the `'option_name' => 'current_theme'` value in wp_options . Is the `option_value` the same as your active theme name?
Try activating your theme also

hope it helps..